# Elasticsearch - http settings how to set up on kubernetes

Tags: elasticsearch

I have Elasticsearch installed on kubernetes.
Could you tell me how can I set up this option: `http.max_content_length`

```
apiVersion: elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/v1beta1
kind: Elasticsearch
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch-sample
spec:
  version: 7.5.0
  nodeSets:
  - name: default
    config:
      node.master: true
      node.data: true
      node.ingest: true
      node.ml: true
      http.max_content_length: 300 <--is this a proper place ?
    count: 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but you are missing a unit of this size, please add it as well.

```
http.max_content_length: 300mb --> note `mb`
```

Comment: If you would like to be more helpful - can you please have a look here :)  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64683429/problem-with-seting-up-of-index-lifecycle